# Proving $\left||a+b|^p-|b|^p\right| \leq \epsilon |b|^p + C|a|^p$

Tags: inequality

Let $p>0$. We want to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a constant $C$ such that for all complex numbers $a, b$ the following inequality holds:

$$
||a+b|^p-|b|^p| \leq \epsilon |b|^p + C|a|^p.
$$

Using that $x \rightarrow |x|^p $ is convex for $p>1$ we have for $\lambda \in [0,1]$:

$$
|a+b|^p \leq (|a| + |b|)^p \leq (1-\lambda)^{1-p} |a|^p + \lambda^{1-p} |b|^p.
$$

So by choosing $\lambda = (1+\epsilon)^{\frac{1}{1-p}}$ we get

$$
|a+b|^p-|b|^p \leq \epsilon |b|^p + C|a|^p.
$$

where $C= (1- \lambda)^{1-p}$.

For $0<p<1$ we can use that $|a+b|^p \leq |a|^p + |b|^p$ and also get that

$$
|a+b|^p-|b|^p \leq \epsilon |b|^p + C|a|^p
$$

by choosing $C=1$ and adding $\epsilon |b|^p$ on the right hand side.

So we have proven that for $p > 0$
$$
|a+b|^p-|b|^p \leq \epsilon |b|^p + C|a|^p.
$$

But this is a weaker statement than what we wanted to prove. How can we deduce the stronger first one?

Comment: Idea: Apply what you have found to $b^{\prime}=a+b$ and $a^{\prime}=-a$. So you will get a bound on $|b|^p-|a+b|^p$. With the bounds you have on $|a+b|^p$ in the two case you have done, may be you can finish.